# Godzilla like creature vs. a giant robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, kaiju

When I was a child, I watched a movie which was dubbed in my native language.

In that movie, a giant creature looking like Godzilla or a dinosaur came from the sea. The creature laid an egg and the egg was taken by scientists for research.

To attack that creature, the scientist built a giant robot which looked like the same creature. At some point in the movie when the original creature and bot were fighting, there was insufficient power for the bot and an external power source was used.

Does anyone know that movie?

Comment: What is your native language? About when did you watch this?

Comment: Tamil.. i am from Tamilnadu, India

Comment: Thanks. When I asked for that, I thought it would help narrow it down, but the question had already been answered. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [Godzilla vs Mechagodzilla 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Mechagodzilla_II).

> In that movie, a giant creature looking like godzilla or dinosaur will come from the sea..

Godzilla usually (maybe always - I haven't seen all of the movies) comes from the sea.

> The creature will lay a egg and the egg will taken by scientists for research..

Scientists find what they believe is a pteranodon egg and attempt to take it.

> To attack that creature, the scientist will build a giant robot which looks like the same creature..

The United Nations Godzilla Countermeasures Center uses the remains of Mechagodzilla to create a robot of their own.

[image: Mechagodzilla 2]

> At some point of the movie when the original creature and bot were fighting, there ll be power insufficient for the bot and external power source will be given..

The Mechagodzilla robot malfunctions and falls to Godzilla. After being repaired, it combines with [Garuda](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Garuda) to become Super-Mechagodzilla.

Garuda could easily be described as a "flying tank like structure".

[image: Garuda]

The combined Super-Mechagodzilla:

[image: Super-Mechagodzilla]

Comment: could please tell me in what way the repair will be done?? Because in the movie i watched, a flying tank like structure will flew to the bot

Comment: Thanks phantom42, paul thats the movie i was looking for

Comment: @arunborn2win41 I added some photos, including one of Garuda. It could easily be called a "flying tank like structure".

Comment: I thought I was the only watcher of "rubber-suit Godzilla" movies. Well done, [Phantom42](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/5184/phantom42)!

Comment: @Thaddeus you will always have company